# Safe way for parallel random sampling in python3

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, numpy, random, parallel-processing

I need to repeat N times a scientific simulation based on a random sampling, easily:

```
results = [mysimulation() for i in range(N)]
```

Since every simulation require minutes, I'd like to parallelize them in order to reduce the execution time. Some weeks ago I successfully analyzed some simpler cases, for which I wrote my code in C using OpenMP and functions like rand_r() for avoiding seed overlapping. How could I obtain a similar effect in Python?

I tried reading more about python3 multithreading/parallelization, but I found no results concerning the random generation. Conversely, numpy.random does not suggest anything in this direction (as far as I found).

Comment: you could look into hashing, that what we do in realtime computer graphism when we need a lot of random sampling, hash with a specifique value (like thread id + time + i) and you will get some random sampling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practices for seeding random and numpy.random in the same program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58954557/best-practices-for-seeding-random-and-numpy-random-in-the-same-program)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56009927/is-this-proper-use-of-numpy-seeding-for-parallel-code/56010589#56010589